# jQuery will only work after page refresh

Tags: jquery

I'm terrible at anything Javascript, so I think this is really easy, but I think the way I'm searching for an answer is wrong. I'm trying to add a class with jQuery to images that are taller than they are wide (portrait).  My jquery looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var imgs = $(".isLandscape");
    imgs.each(function(){
        var img = $(this);
        var width = img.width();
        var height = img.height();

        if(width < height){
            img.parent('li').addClass('portrait');
        }
    })
});
```

It works after I refresh the page after an initial page load.  To clarify: Page loads for the first time, the `.isLandscape` is not added to `<li>` element.  I refresh the page, `.isLandscape` class is added to `<li>` element and everything is how I want it to be on the first load.  What am I missing?

A few things I've tried:

1. `(window).on("load", function...`. instead of `(document).ready...` and a few different variations.
2. Loading the jquery in the `<head>` vs the in the `'
3. a bunch of random stuff that I googled.

Some things that might help someone help me:

1. It's a wordpress site.
2. Obviously I'm terrible at javascript.

Thanks for your help in advance.

### Edit

Thanks for everyone's help.  The tip that helped me was I wasn't listening for everything to be completely loaded.  This is my final code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(window).load(function(){
    $(".isLandscape").each(function(){
        var img = $(this);
        var width = img.width();
        var height = img.height();

        if(width < height){
            img.parent('li').addClass('portrait');
        }
    })
  });
});
```

I needed to:
1. make sure the dom was ready `jQuery(document).ready`.

2. them make sure everything was loaded `$(window).load(function...`, which is the same as `$(window).on("load", function()...` I believe.

Just a note for those who find this:

I tried instead of `window`, using `"img"` or `".isLandscape"` to see if the specific elements were loaded and neither worked.  I think because there were many images and images with the class `.isLandscape` on the page, but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: You should be listening for image load, your code just hopes it is loaded.

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3877079/559079) also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See more info above in my original question:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(window).load(function(){
    $(".isLandscape").each(function(){
        var img = $(this);
        var width = img.width();
        var height = img.height();

        if(width < height){
            img.parent('li').addClass('portrait');
        }
    })
  });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

So I did not know your html structure and when `.isLandscape` added to `<li>` tag,I can only gives you some pseudo code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('load','.isLandscape',function(event){
        var img = $(event.currentTarget);
        var width = img.width();
        var height = img.height();

        if(width < height){
            img.parent('li').addClass('portrait');
        }
  });
});
```

docs about [jquery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).The second `document` can be a parent tag of all `.isLandscape` and the `load` event can be the event when `.isLandscape` added to the `<li>` tag.